# Linq-to-SQL WHERE IN statement returns more than is wanted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

Okay I am trying to make a partial view and controller whose job it is to select and display a list of accessories for whatever product is currently being viewed in the parent view.

The database I am working again stores this information in a field that is formatted as a comma separated list, like this:

```
productnr,productnr2,productnr3,productnr4
```

So I use the following code to retrieve this list and use it to run the equivalent of an SQL WHERE IN statement:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _ListAccessories(string Artnr)
{
    var List = (
        from ArtTbl in db.ArtTbl
        where ArtTbl.ArticleNr == Artnr
        select ArtTbl.AccessoryList)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    var AccList = customFunctions.Accessories(text);

    var AccQuery = 
        from Art in db.ArtTbl
        where AccList.Contains(ArtTbl.ArticleNr)
        select new AccessoryList
        {
            Artnr = ArtTbl.ArticleNr,
            Name = ArtTbl.Namefield_1,
        };

    return PartialView(AccQuery);
}
```

The function in the AccList variable transforms the first string into the result below. I did this because all the examples I saw used such a syntax, the function seems to work properly as I've tested by sending it as a viewBag to the view just to check that it looks correct:

```
"productnr", "productnr2", "productnr3", "productnr4"
```

This is what the AccessoryList model looks like as well, just a very simple model:

```
public class AccessoryList 
{
    public string Artnr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AccessoryList()
    {
    }
}
```

Now this code works, but the problem is that it is too generous, if I have a product number in the list that says "AP500W" then it will also return "AP500" or just "500". This is a problem as it should only return the exact match.

Comment: Maybe out of topic, but have you considered (if possible) to not store to comma separated values. What if you need to search for rows that have particular 'productnr'? Normally querying this kind of column is really nasty compared to having products in a separate table.

Comment: Locked into some other programs database, have to make do with what we got.

Comment: I understand, this happens quite often that database is beyond "refactoring" because of other apps or some other reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're having problems begins and ends with this:

> The database I am working again stores this information in a field
>   that is formatted as a comma separated list

LINQ is translating this to a SQL statement that is treating the *entire field value* as a single entity - because it **is** a single entity. When `Contains()` is evaluated, it's simply looking for matching substring values. That's why `AP500` and `500` match `AP500W`.

Since you're really trying to do the equivalent of `WHERE IN (...)` you'll need to convert your MVA (multi-valued attribute) into a set of distinct values.

The query works in your example where you send a view bag of *individual string values*:

```
"productnr", "productnr2", "productnr3", "productnr4"
```

Your database value is actually *a single string value*:

```
"productnr, productnr2, productnr3, productnr4"
```

The difference is subtle but very important. Notice in the second example there is only **one string of data** that acts as a single value.

Comment: I vaguely figured it was something like that but thought I had gotten it right anyway because it did spit out quotes around every value and looked proper, I guess the solution is to split up the string.

Comment: Thank you, tried today to instead turned the result into a list and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Dennis,

I know the following wont *exactly* answer your problem. However, it may bring you closer to a resolution. In your example, you are saying:

```
where AccList.Contains(ArtTbl.ArticleNr)
```

this is why you are getting wildcard results *across* the resultset. One way to mitigate this would be to only examine the front portion of the result string:

```
where AccList.StartsWith(ArtTbl.ArticleNr)
```

you could even have a look at (tho i'm certain this won't work):

```
where AccList.Any(x => x.StartsWith(ArtTbl.ArticleNr))
```

in the above case, you'd get results for `'AP50', 'AP500'` etc, etc. May be worth further investigation (i'm not at a compiler right now, so can't validate if the above works as expected or not :-)).